Generating random number (dice roll) and storing into array
I'm a new ARM programmer and I have a project that I'm working on where I generate a random number between 1-6 (simulating a dice roll) and store that value into an array. Then I want to print that array, and then return the number of runs (a sequence of adjacent repeated values) in the array. Here's what I have so far:
@ Define Raspberry Pi
.cpu    cortex-a53
.fpu    neon-fp-armv8
.syntax unified

@ Define data
.data
    print_roll: .asciz "%d "
    run_len: .asciz "\nRun length: %d"
    tot_run: .asciz "\nTotal number of runs: %d"
.text
    .align 2
    .global main
    .type main, %function

main:
    @ Save link register
    push {lr}
    mov r0, #400 @ reserve 400 bits for array
    bl malloc @ dynamically allocate memory
    mov r4, r0 @ array in r4
    mov r10, #0 @ index 0
    mov r0, #0 
    bl time
    bl srand
    b roll_dice @ start rolling dice
roll_dice:
    cmp r10, #100 @ if i >= 100
    bge print_array @ yes? loop over
    @ no? continue looping
    bl rand @ store random number in r0
    and r0, r0, #0x7FFFFFFF               @ mask to ensure a positive number
    udiv r2, r0, r1               @ r2 = rand / 6
    mul r2, r2, r1                @ r2 = (rand / 6) * 6
    sub r0, r0, r2                @ r0 = rand - ((rand / 6) * 6)
    add r0, r0, #1                @ final = (rand % 6) + 1
    
    @ store in array
    mov r2, r10, lsl #2 @ i*4
    str r0, [r4, r2] @ load 
    
    add r10, r10, #1
    b roll_dice @ loop

print_array:
    mov r10, #0
    b print_loop    
print_loop:
    cmp r10, #100
    bge count_run

    mov r2, r10, lsl #2
    ldr r0, [r4, r2]
    ldr r0, =print_roll
    bl printf

    add r10, r10, #1 @ i++
    b print_loop @ loop
count_run:
    mov r2, #0 @ currentNum
    mov r3, #1 @ rollCount
    mov r5, #0 @ totalRuns
    mov r10, #0 @ index
    b count_run_loop

count_run_loop:
    cmp r10, #100
    bge done
    mov r6, r10, lsl #2
    ldr r7, [r4, r6] @ arr[i]
    cmp r7, r2
    beq equal_case
    cmp r3, #1
    bgt print_run_len
    mov r2, r7
    mov r3, #1

    add r10, r10, #1
    b count_run_loop

print_run_len:
    mov r0, r3
    ldr r0, =run_len
    add r5, r5, #1
    add r10, r10, #1
    b count_run @ loop

equal_case:
    add r3, r3, #1 @ rollCount++
    add r10, r10, #1
    b count_run @ loop
done:
    mov r0, r5
    ldr r0, =tot_run
    bl printf
    mov r0, r4
    bl free
    pop {lr}
    bx lr


And here's what's being output:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Total number of runs: 0

If anyone could explain if my number generator even works or if I'm printing the values correctly that would be great. Thank you all
I wrote the program in C, which is what I'm trying to translate that logic from. The program should run similar to the way this works:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* roll_dice(int arr[]){
    int* rolls = arr;

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        int random_number = (rand() % (6 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

        arr[i] = random_number;
    }
    return rolls;
}

void count_run(int arr[]){
    int* rolls = arr;
    int currentNum = arr[0];
    int rollCount = 1;
    int totalRuns = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++){
        if(arr[i] == currentNum){
            rollCount++;
        }else{
            if(rollCount>1){
                printf("\nRun length: %d", rollCount);
                totalRuns++;
            }
            currentNum = arr[i];
            rollCount = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("\nTotal number of runs: %d", totalRuns);
}

int main(){
    int rolls[100];
    roll_dice(rolls);

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        printf("%d  ", rolls[i]);
    }

    count_run(rolls);
    return 0;
}

And output something like:
6  6  5  5  6  5  1  1  5  3  6  6  2  4  2  6  2  3  4  1  4  1  3  4  5  5  4  3  3  6  6  1  6  1  4  5  6  2  2  1  6  4  3  4  4  3  4  2  6  5  6  3  5  4  4  2  6  4  2  5  5  6  3  1  1  5  5  3  5  5  3  4  3  4  5  3  1  4  4  3  4  6  1  5  1  3  5  3  6  5  1  4  3  2  6  5  3  1  4  6  
Run length: 2
Run length: 2
Run length: 2
Run length: 2
Run length: 2
Run length: 2
Run length: 2
Run length: 2
Run length: 2
Run length: 2
Run length: 2
Run length: 2
Run length: 2
Run length: 2
Run length: 2
Total number of runs: 15

I basically looked up different ways to generate a random number, but I think my main issue is how I'm storing it into the array and how I'm accessing it. Any help is appreciated

For starters you forgot to load 6 into r1. Also your code does not follow convention with regards to preserving registers but that's not the cause of your issue.

You can get a C compiler to make an example for you with gcc -Og, -O1, or -O2.  https://godbolt.org/z/8ch3jsY6h .  Keep in mind that function calls clobber some registers; your main loop looks ok in that respect, R4 and R10 are call-preserved (What registers to save in the ARM C calling convention?)
